# What Parametric Equations are required to move along a circle while moving left?

Tags: parametric

I'm working on a program where I can set objects along arbitrary parametric paths.

Moving left is easy:

`X = x - dT(V)`

`Y = y`

Moving in a circle is easy:

`X = x+ Cos(dt*Pi)`

`Y = y+ Sin(dt*Pi)`

So I tried to combine them to move left while also moving in a circle, likeso:

`X = x- dT(V) + Cos(dt*Pi)`

`Y = y + Sin(dt*Pi)`

However, this didn't give me the circular movement towards the left that I expected. My goal is a parametric equation where the object will move along the circumference of the circle with a constant speed.

How can I adjust the parametric equation to achieve both constant speed along the x axis and along the radius of the circle? The rotational speed and the leftwards speed need not be the same, just constant relative to each other.

Comment: Take a look at the cycloid.  It might give you some ideas.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I'm asking for the impossible.

Constant rotational speed along a circle is... a circle.

The equation above will provide the expected path. (Though it might help proving it if you have more than a single point involved in visualizing it)